# Как передать данные через POST запрос PHP скрипту на C/C++

Tags: c++

Как передать данные через POST запрос PHP скрипту на C/C++. Мне необходимо создать приложение на C/C++, которое из под Windows будет отправлять данные от пользователя на Web-сервер методом POST скрипту PHP. Буду очень рад, если у кого есть работающие примеры кода на С/С++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например, с помощью curl. [Примеры](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/example.html), в том числе и как сделать post запрос. То, что на сервере php, не имеет абсолютно никакого значения.